# Blender doesn't render Cycles with GPU?

Tags: rendering

I was messing around with effect and when I went to start a brand new scene to render something that doesn't use effects nothing shows up until I switch render with CPU?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of now, you need a CUDA capable card in order to leverage GPU renders reliably.  OpenSL for AMD cards are hit or miss right now.  The rendering guide also suggests that your card may not have enough memory.

https://www.blender.org/manual/render/cycles/gpu_rendering.html

Comment: The scene I am trying to render is a couple of MB and my GPU is a GTX770

Comment: It worked fine before I started using effects

Comment: What you mean by "effect"? For example, rendering  "smoke and fire"? Or what? Older Blender versions can't use volume shaders when "Attribute" node is connected to shader's "Density" input. You can also check "Feature Set" in "Render" tab and try both: "Supported" and "Experimental." BTW: did you see your graphic card in "User preferences" -> "System"

Answer (score 0):

Of course you have to turn it on in the User Preferences under System via CUDA button (Cycles Compute Device). The Camera Render Device on GPU Compute pull down is grayed out if not enabled.

There are other GLSL options that speed up subdivisions for animation morphs and that is also turned on per object.

It seems the CUDA setting is not saved with the file, and you have to remember to turn it on manually.